# How can I use SQL IN Operator with Objectdatasource?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have done IN statement straight to SQL but I was trying to use it the objecdatasource. I have a textbox where users need query multiple item codes like this 1001,1002,1003 but how can I use this IN statement with a parameter with objectdatasource?

TIA

Comment: Check this out http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/116/Parameterized-IN-clauses-with-ADO.NET-and-LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the textbox value of "1,2,3" to the parameter as a full string, and split the contents by "," within the object your passing the data to.